# How to make an alias from a statement with many : " and many : '

Tags: zsh, alias

How to make this an alias in zsh?

```
svn status | grep "^?" | awk -F "      " '{print $2}' | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 svn add
```

I know it should be something along the lines:

```
alias sall = "the command"
```

But as the line mixes " with ' I don't know how to handle that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use " for your awk command.

```
alias sall='svn status | grep "^?" | awk -F " " "{print $2}" | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 svn add'
```

should work.

Comment: The escaped characters version gives an error about a ' not being matched. But the first version works, if you make it __alias sall='svn st...'__ (no whitespace)

Comment: @Nerian: If you use double quotes around the awk command, you'll need to escape the dollar sign: `awk -F " " "{print \$2}"`

Comment: Sorry, Bash needs it. Apparently zsh doesn't. After trying both, I see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function.

```
sall() {
    svn status | sed -rn 's/^\? {7}//p' | xargs -d '\n' svn add
}
```

(Since `svn` uses newline as output separator, it makes no sense to convert it to null and back.)